# Displaying a list of records in a Message Dialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe, joptionpane

Here is the situation , i have a doctor record array where there are attributes such as first name , doctor id , contact number , etc. I am trying to display all the registered doctors ids and their contact numbers in a JOptionPane Message Dialog, I want this to happen when  i press a button.  It should be displayed as a list.

Is this possible ? I have tried it but i only managed to get one record  displayed, other records are all jumbled.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be straig forward

sample:

doctor class

```
package com.doc;

public class Doctor {

    private String name;
    private int id;

    public Doctor(String name, int id) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

doctor demo

```
package com.doc;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DoctorDemo {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Doctor> doctors = new ArrayList<Doctor>();

        // populate from database
        // im hard coding
        doctors.add(new Doctor("Test", 1));
        doctors.add(new Doctor("Test2", 2));
        doctors.add(new Doctor("Test3", 3));
        String message = "\n Doctor records \n ";
        for (Doctor doc : doctors) {
            message += "\n\n\n" + "Name:" + doc.getName() + "Id:" + doc.getId();
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    }
}
```

This shows how to display in joption message dialog.